# Given a set of conditions, prove that there exists a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This problem comes from the book Real Analysis, by Folland section 2.2 problem 7,

Background information: The problem says to use exercise 4 which is here and I will also provide the proof for

If $f:X\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $f^{-1}((r,\infty])\in M$ for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $f$ is measurable.

Proof: Let us suppose that $r\in \mathbb{R}$ then there is a sequence $\left(r_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}\cap (r,\infty)$ converging to $r$, and we have that $$f^{-1}((r,\infty]) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f^{-1}((r,\infty])\in M$$ since $B_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$ is generated from such intervals $(r,\infty]$ from proposition 1.2, it follows that $f$ is measurable.

Also, if needed refer to this link for [proposition 1.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394864/borel-sigma-algebra)

Here is problem 7: Suppose that for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we are given a set $E_\alpha\in M$ such that $E_\alpha\subset E_\beta$ whenever $\alpha < \beta,\bigcup_{\alpha\in \mathbb{R}} E_\alpha = X$, and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}}E_\alpha = \emptyset$. Then there is a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\leq \alpha$ on $E_\alpha$ and $f(x)\geq \alpha$ on $E_{\alpha}^{c}$ for every $\alpha$. (Use exercise 4)

I am not sure how to prove this, I want to do this problem myself but I just need some hints, suggestions, or guidance on how to prove this. This is not for an assignment just for practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking of the $E_\alpha$s as level sets of the function $f$ to be constructed, it's natural to try $f(x):=\inf\{q\in\Bbb Q: x\in E_q\}$. (Cf. Folland's proof of Urysohn's Lemma (4.15) on p. 122 of your text. I here use only rational $q$s because measurability cooperates with countable operations.)
Key observation: $f(x)\le\alpha$ if and only if $x\in\cap_{q>\alpha,q\in\Bbb Q}E_q$.